# MYSQL adding columns value of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a problem in which I have a STUDENT table as

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| roll_number | name        | subject_one | subject_two | subject_three |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|           1 |  Sheila     |          32 |          48 |            64 |
|           2 | Rachel      |          24 |          21 |            25 |
|           3 | Christopher |          55 |          12 |            10 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I want the print the output as

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| roll_number | name        | total       | 
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|           1 |  Sheila     |          144|
|           2 | Rachel      |          70 |     
|           3 | Christopher |          77 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

and select all student having marks greater than 75 ??
How can I achieve this using MYSQL ??

Comment: What's the problem? `subject_one + subject_two + subject_three`

Comment: You don't need aggregate functions. Those are for combining values in multiple rows. You just use normal arithmetic for combining columns in the same row.

Comment: total marks > 75 or individual marks greater than 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need the [aggregate functions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) and using them is enough. I am not sure if it can help you or not.

```
SELECT roll_number , name , (subject_one + subject_two + subject_three) AS total FROM STUDENT HAVING total > 75 ;
```

Comment: Without group by Having clause isn't work

Comment: Its working depending on your business.

Comment: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug127.htm

Comment: Looks like for WHERE clause to work the column should be present in TABLE, while the case is different with having, bcoz the same query works with HAVING but not with WHERE.

Comment: yeah you are correct @JayYadav